# array_push strings which comes from json_encode for sql insertion

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, string

Hello I would like to store string which comes from json encode to get it store in MySQL, but the thing is that the array returned nothing. Here is my code:

```
    $com = array("1-1","1-2","1-3");
    $classcom=array();
    for ($i=1; $i<(int)$totaleleve; $i++) {
      $eleve=array();
      foreach($com as $value)
       {
        array_push($eleve,'2');

       }
       $final="'".json_encode($eleve)."'";
       array_push($classcom,$final);
       echo $final;
       echo $classcom;
    }
    echo $classcom;
```

For your information, `$totaleleve='20'`, and  I do `$final="'".json_encode($eleve)."'";` so that I can concentrate strings of the array to be able to insert it into the SQL statement, which looks something like this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO table VALUES (".explode(",", $classcom).")"
// so that it looks like something like this:
$sql="INSERT INTO table VALUES ('["2","2","2"]','["2","2","2"]','["2","2","2"]')
```

the `$final` gave me `'["2","2","2"]'` which i wanted, but when i do `array_push($classcom,$final);`, it just gave me a blank array :

```
Array
```

Can someone help me, please? Thank you!

Comment: var_dump to print whatever type is your variable, echo only for string type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$totaleleve` is greater than 0 the array is not empty. Just use `print_r` or `var_dump` to show its values.

```
print_r($classcom)
```

Instead of `echo $classcom`

Answer (score 1):

Just write  `print_r($classcom);` instead of `echo $classcom;` and you will see that your array isn't empty.

Comment: Thanks it worked but i am sorry if i didn't make your answer because people answered before you